# ngx-datatable An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ngx-datatable, ionic5

I am facing an error while trying to add `ngx-datatable` in to my `ionic + angular` project. I am receiving hundereds of error lines and it seems it doesn't add `ngx-database` into my project. I am following [Add ngx-datatable with ionic 5](https://www.positronx.io/create-ionic-data-table-with-ngx-datatable/) to add `ngx-datatable` into my project.

package.json

```
"@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
"@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
"@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
"@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
"@ionic-native/core": "^5.0.7",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.0.0",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.0.0",
"@ionic/angular": "^5.0.0",
"@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^17.0.0",
"core-js": "^2.5.4",
"rxjs": "~6.5.1",
"tslib": "^1.9.0",
"zone.js": "~0.9.1"
```

in app/home.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HomePage } from './home.page';
import { HomePageRoutingModule } from './home-routing.module';
import { NgxDatatableModule } from '@swimlane/ngx-datatable';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    HomePageRoutingModule, NgxDatatableModule
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

and the errors

```
ERROR in node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/lib/components/body/body-cell.component.d.ts:8:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
[ng] 8     set group(group: any);

node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/lib/components/body/body-cell.component.d.ts:9:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
[ng] 9     get group(): any;
```

I guess my version of `ionic+angular` is not compatible or `ngx-datatable` is not compatable or any other errors which I am struggling with.

Comment: yes, latest version of ngx-datatable is not compaitable with angular. you just update ngx-datatable version to 16.1.1  in package.json file.Delete node_modules folder and run npm install command. this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved it. `ngx-datatable` version `17.0.0` was not compatible with the ionic + angular versions I have in the package.json file. I simply installed `ngx-datatable` 16.1.1 version and that solved the problem.

```
npm i @swimlane/ngx-datatable@16.1.1 --save
```